# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, entity-framework-6

I have problem in this code

```
var result = context.SallBillDetails.Where(s => s.SaleBill.Date >= starTime && s.SaleBill.Date <= endTime)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.TypeDetail.TypeInfo.Name)
                       .Select(d => new
                       {
                           Id = d.Key.ToString(),
                           TypeName = d.FirstOrDefault().TypeDetail.TypeInfo.Name.ToString(),
                           Qty = d.Sum(c => c.Qty).ToString(),
                           SallPrice = d.Sum(c => c.UnitPrice).ToString(),
                           TotalCoastOfType = d.Sum(c => c.TotalPrice).ToString(),
                           Taks = d.Sum(c => c.Taks).ToString(),
                           TaksPercetnage = settings.TaksValue.ToString().ToString(),
                           TotalWithTaks = d.Sum(c => c.TotalWithTaks).ToString(),
                           RevenuPersentage = d.Sum(c => c.RevenuPersentage),
                           WelcomString = settings.WelcomeString.ToString(),
                           CompanyName = settings.CompanyName.ToString(),
                           Sum = 0
                       }).ToList();
```

this exception occure

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Non-static method requires a target.

[The Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPWsl.png)

Comment: Almost certainly something is null, that's usually why this exception happens. Only you can debug this.

Comment: All those `.ToString()` seem so useless there, specially on properties like `Name` and `CompanyName`. What's the point of all of that?

Comment: no it can work correctly on visual 2015 and when work it in visual 2017 not work

Comment: #Camilo Terevinto edit it and the problem is still